# How to run a parameter as an alias in a shell script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, alias

I have an alias `alias ll='ls -lF'`;

I created a bash script `temp.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash 

# Allow aliases to work in bash NON-interactive mode!
shopt -s expand_aliases

# .. and load them
source ~/.bash_aliases
$1
```

but when I run it it gives me:

```
$ ./temp.sh ll
./temp.sh: line 10: ll: command not found
```

and when I change the script and put the alias directly:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash 

# Allow aliases to work in bash NON-interactive mode!
shopt -s expand_aliases

# .. and load them
source ~/.bash_aliases
ll
```

... it's working:

```
$ ./temp.sh   
total 12
-rwxrwxr-x 1 sobi3ch sobi3ch 423 Apr 19 14:21 script.sh*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 sobi3ch sobi3ch 196 Apr 26 12:28 temp.sh*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 sobi3ch sobi3ch 173 Apr 26 12:02 script2.sh
```

... also when I run the `alias` command in the script instead of `ll` (or `$1`) I can see the alias to `ll` between all aliases.

Why doesn't my alias work when I pass it as parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not explicitly pointed out in the documentation (at least nowhere that I could notice), but the problem is that alias expansion takes precedence over variable expansion; that means that the `$1` token is checked to see if it corresponds to an alias, discarded as a potential alias and only after that expanded as a parameter. Since there's no command named `ll`, Bash errors out.

You could use `eval` to make the parameter expand twice, the first time as a parameter and the second time as an alias:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash 

# Allow aliases to work in bash NON-interactive mode!
shopt -s expand_aliases

# .. and load them
source ~/.bash_aliases
eval "$1"
```

```
~$ cat temp.sh 
#!/bin/bash 

# Allow aliases to work in bash NON-interactive mode!
shopt -s expand_aliases

# .. and load them
source .bash_aliases
eval "$1"  
~$ cat .bash_aliases 
alias ll='ls -l'
~$ ./temp.sh ll
drwxrwxr-x  3 user user 4096 apr 24 15:18 articles
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user 4096 apr 24 00:20 bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096 apr 21 20:22 Documenti
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 8980 apr 21 20:18 examples.desktop
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096 apr 21 21:59 Immagini
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096 apr 21 20:22 Modelli
drwxrwxr-x  6 user user 4096 apr 23 20:45 MT7630E
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096 apr 21 20:22 Musica
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096 apr 21 20:22 Pubblici
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096 apr 24 23:02 Scaricati
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096 apr 24 13:44 Scrivania
-rwxrwxr-x  1 user user  149 apr 26 13:22 temp.sh
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user 4096 apr 26 13:22 tmp
drwxrwxr-x 24 user user 4096 apr 23 13:45 util-linux-2.28
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096 apr 21 20:22 Video
```

Comment: And that's the answer! :)

Comment: @sobi3ch I suggest keeping a list with the order of the various shell expansions handy. Lots of time *not* wasted in fixing these things. ;)